# On the error during telephony manager null-checking on a specific device

Tags: android, telephonymanager

I trying to save their phone numbers after checking permissions and USIM state.

In onCreate() methods, Initialized global variable TelephonyManager.

```
mTelephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
```

TelephonyManager initialized, but checked Null on a specific device(Galaxy S3).

```
// Null value confirmed here even though initialized
if(mTelephonyManager != null) {
    if (mTelephonyManager.getSimState() == TelephonyManager.SIM_STATE_ABSENT 
        || mTelephonyManager.getSimState() == TelephonyManager.SIM_STATE_UNKNOWN) {
        // not USIM
        numFlag = false;
        finish();
    } else if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE) 
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        //Permission Check
        numFlag = false;
        finish();
    } else {
        // For security reasons, test in the following ways
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(SharedUtil.getInstance().getString(this, "phoneNumber"))) {
            // PhoneNumber Init...
        } else {
            // Data Saved...
        }
    }
}else{
    Toast.makeText(SmartIdActivity.this, "Unable to save phone number.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    finish();
}
```

Am I wrong or is this a special issue?

Comment: I also faced same issue some days ago.After research i got to know telephony manager will give you null on some of devices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some devices will return null when the sim card is not installed on the devices. Some devices will raise an exception when you're trying to call the following code:

```
TelephonyManager telMgr = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
```

So, you need to handle both of them. Something like this:

```
private boolean isSimCardAvailable() {
  try {
    TelephonyManager telMgr = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    if (telMgr == null) return false;
    int simState = telMgr.getSimState();
    switch (simState) {
      case TelephonyManager.SIM_STATE_NETWORK_LOCKED:
      case TelephonyManager.SIM_STATE_PIN_REQUIRED:
      case TelephonyManager.SIM_STATE_PUK_REQUIRED:
      case TelephonyManager.SIM_STATE_READY:
      case TelephonyManager.SIM_STATE_NOT_READY:
        return true;
      case TelephonyManager.SIM_STATE_UNKNOWN:
      case TelephonyManager.SIM_STATE_ABSENT:
        //SIM card state: SIM Card Error, permanently disabled
      case TelephonyManager.SIM_STATE_PERM_DISABLED:
        // SIM card state: SIM Card Error, present but faulty
      case TelephonyManager.SIM_STATE_CARD_IO_ERROR:
        // SIM card state: SIM Card restricted, present but not usable due to
        //carrier restrictions.
      case TelephonyManager.SIM_STATE_CARD_RESTRICTED:
        return false;

      default:
        return false;
    }
  } catch (Exception e) {
    Log.e("TAG", "Exception e = " + e.toString());
    return false;
  }
}
```